# Bluetooth headset stuttering

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I recently brought a OneAudio studio wireless headset but I have found that when I connect it to my laptop it stutters a lot. My laptop is a Lenovo G510 and uses Windows 10

I have also tried the headset on a Chromebook and a Samsung phone. It works fine on the phone but not as well on the Chromebook.

I have tried running the sound and Bluetooth troubleshooters and my Bluetooth drivers are up to date. The headset is fully charged and within range of the laptop and I have no other Bluetooth devices so I know this is not a problem. I have also tried disabling handsfree telephony and audio sink in the device properties.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this occur when streaming, or playback only? Does this occur in video playback only, or both audio and video? Streaming uses more CPU than playback, video+audio more than audio only.

Comment: Have you tried turning off WiFi on your laptops while testing the headset? WiFi channels 1-14 (1-11 only in North America) and Bluetooth can both use 2.4GHz frequencies, and there could be interference (unless your WiFi uses 5GHz frequencies, channels 36 and up).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning off Wi-Fi on your laptops while testing the headset? Wi-Fi channels 1-14 (1-11 only in North America) and Bluetooth can both use 2.4GHz frequencies, and there could be interference (unless your Wi-Fi uses 5GHz frequencies, channels 36 and up).